# Changing the position of an array element without affecting it's structure

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm integrating a chat page.Below is the list of chat users.However users can access chat page in two ways

1) http://domain/chat

In general,The output be like

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [creater_id] => 6
                [receiver_id] => 7
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [creater_id] => 6
                [receiver_id] => 11
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [creater_id] => 6
                [receiver_id] => 13
            )

    )
```

2) http://domain/chat?receiver_id=11
In this case,I want the output like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [creater_id] => 6
            [receiver_id] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [creater_id] => 6
            [receiver_id] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [creater_id] => 6
            [receiver_id] => 13
        )

)
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You need to use order by in chat page in mysql query.

Comment: If I use order_by, it will sort the array.But what I need is,to make the specific array element at the top of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array to sort is $arr, and the needed first key is $receiver_id

```
uksort($arr, function($a, $b) use($receiver_id, $arr) {
    if($arr[$a]["receiver_id"] == $receiver_id) {
        return -1;
    } elseif($arr[$b]["receiver_id"] == $receiver_id) { 
        return 1;
    } else {
        return $a < $b ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to sort from MYSQL but you can try this as well.

```
$a = array(array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2), array('a' => 3, 'b' => 4), array('a' => 5, 'b' => 6), array('a' => 7, 'b' => 8)); 

$temp = array();

            foreach ($a as $key => $value)
            {
                if($value['b'] == 6)
                {
                    $temp[] = $a[$key];

                    unset($a[$key]);
                }
            }

     echo "<pre>";  
     print_r(array_merge($temp , $a)); exit;
```